# Salesforce Infrastructure monitoring

Tags: architecture

Have anyone take a look at possible monitoring tools for Salesforce?
I would like to monitor Salesforce servers for avaliability, traffic and performance. Any input would be appreciated

Comment: Salesforce publishes that data in HTML format - see e.g. https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances or https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/performance and linked pages.